# Reset ID of rows after deleting or adding data in Entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, dbcontext

I have a `DbSet` of objects on which I preform CRUD operations. My question is how to reset the value of the ID upon deleting or adding a new item. My class structure is outlined below:

```
public class Guitar
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

I add or delete objects like so:

```
public void Add(Guitar g)
{
    try
    {
        lock (context)
        {
            context.Guitars.Add(g);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
    }
}

public void Delete(int id)
{
    Guitar g = context.Guitars.Find(id);
    context.Guitars.Remove(g);
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

If I delete the last row for example with an ID of 5 it works. But when I add another I expect it's ID to be 5 but instead it is 6.

Comment: Well, this is how database `Identity` columns work - they don't "reset" (update) when the value is deleted and don't fill the gaps upon new value generation. Hence it's not a EF issue.

Comment: Yes, not an EF issue. I'd suggest you shouldn't be caring about your ID values. If you do need to care about them, perhaps make them a non-key property, and use a property you don't care about as the key. As to reseting the values, it is possible, but it depends on your database provider. For MS SQL Server take a look at DBCC CHECKIDENT with the RESEED option

Comment: Thanks for the info Kevin, was more curious about this too I guess. Was strange for me to see a huge gap between some entries in the DB in terms of their ID value